# A Challenging String Question: Problem with displaying all occurrences' indexes of a substring in a string (C++)

Tags: c++, string, search, substring, alphabetical

What I have to do is simple but my code is not working due to some error I cannot figure out:

1. Check the 0 indexed (the first) element of an input string and decide whether it is the string where I am going to search, i.e. the source string, or the string that I will be searching, i.e. the search string.
   I will denote them as SourceString and SearchString, respectively. As long as the input is not valid, the program should ask me to reenter the string value
2. If the 0 indexed element of the input string is equal to 3, the program should terminate.
3. If the 0 indexed element of the input string is equal to 1, I have to check the rest of the string (that is all other elements of the string with the exception of the first and the second element since the second element is an interval) to see whether it contains any unwanted (invalid) characters which are: anything but lowercase letter from a to z basically - more specifically, the string should NOT contain any numbers or question marks. Also, the string should not be empty. If any of those conditions is not satisfied, the program will ask me to reenter an input. And perform all these checks again. If these checks are satisfied, then I assign the value of the input string to a new string variable I call SourceString (this is the "source" where I am going to search the SearchString).
4. If the 0 indexed element of the input string is equal to 2, then I have to perform a check on the rest of the string (that is all other elements of the string with the exception of the first and the second element since the second element is an interval). The rest of the string should NOT be empty and it should consist only of lowercase letter from a to z. **It can contain question marks but it should not consist only of question marks.** If any of these is not satisfied, the program should ask me to reenter the input until I get it right. When/if all of these conditions are satisfied, then I denote the input string as my search string and call the new variable SearchString. Then I look for the SearchString in the SourceString and print the indexes of all occurrences of the SearchString that I found in the SourceString.
5. These steps are repeated until I enter 3 as my input string, then the program ends.

You can check the following sample run to get a clearer idea of what the program is supposed to do:

```
This program searches a search string in a source string with the option of wildcards.

Example inputs with their meaning in parantheses:

1 thislectureisawesome (to enter a new source string)
2 lecture (to enter a new source string)
2 t?r? (to enter a source string with wildcards)
3 (to exit the program)

Enter your choice and string: 1 changingthesourcestring
Source word has been changed to "changingthesourcestring"

Enter your choice and string: 2 the 
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "the",
"the" has been found at index 8

Enter your choice and string: 2 ing
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "ing",
"ing" has been found at index 5
"ing" has been found at index 20

Enter your choice and string: 2 i?g
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "i?g",
"ing" has been found at index 5
"ing" has been found at index 20

Enter your choice and string: 2 is
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "is", no match has been found.

Enter your choice and string: 2 ?es
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "?es",
"hes" has been found at index 9
"ces" has been found at index 15

Enter your choice and string: 2 ?e?
For the source word "changingthesourcestring" and search word "?e?",
"hes" has been found at index 9
"ces" has been found at index 15

Enter your choice and string: 3
Bye!
```

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void CheckNumber(string InputString)  
{
    while(InputString.at(0) != '1' && InputString.at(0) != '2' && InputString.at(0) != '3')
    {
        cout << "Choice can be 1, 2 or 3! Try again." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice and string: ";
        getline(cin, InputString);
    }
    if(InputString.at(0) == '3')
        cout << "Bye!" << endl;
}

// Checks if the search string is a substring of the source string
int CheckSubstring(string SourceString, string SearchString) 
{ 
    SourceString = SourceString.substr(2,SourceString.length());
    int SourceStringLength = SourceString.length(); 
    int SearchStringLength = SearchString.length(); 
    int LengthDifference = SourceStringLength - SearchStringLength;

    /* A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i <= LengthDifference; i++) { 
        int j; 

        /* For current index i, check for pattern match */
        for (j = 0; j < SearchStringLength; j++) 
            if (SourceString[i + j] != SearchString[j]) 
                break; 

        if (j == SearchStringLength) 
            return i; 
    } 

    return -1; 
} 

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main() 
{ 
    string InputString;
    string SourceString; 
    string SearchString;
    cout << "Enter your choice and string: ";
    getline(cin, InputString);
    CheckNumber(InputString);

    while(InputString.at(0) == '1' || InputString.at(0) == '2')
    {
        int LengthInputString = InputString.length();
        int LengthInputWord = LengthInputString - 2;
        if(InputString.at(0) == '1')
        {
            int CountValid = 0;
            InputString = InputString.substr(2,LengthInputWord);
            if(InputString == "")
            {
                cout << "Wrong input format! Try again." << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter your choice and string: ";
                getline(cin, InputString);
                CheckNumber(InputString);
            }
            for(int i = 1; i <= InputString.length(); i++)
            {
                char c = InputString.at(i);
                if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                {
                    CountValid ++;
                }
            }
            if(CountValid == InputString.length())
            {
                SourceString = InputString;
                cout << "Source word has been changed to \"" << SourceString << "\""  << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Wrong input format! Try again." << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Enter your choice and string: ";
            }
        }
        if(InputString.at(0) == '2')
        {
            int result = CheckSubstring(SourceString, SearchString); 
            if (result == -1) 
                cout << "For the source word \"" << SourceString << "\" and search word \"" << SearchString << "\", no match has been found." << endl;
            else
                cout << "For the source word \"" << SourceString << "\" and search word \"" << SearchString << "\", no match has been found." << result << endl;
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0; 
}
```

The only thing that is working is inputstring 3 and invalid inputstrings: when I choose 3 as input, the program displays "Bye" and terminates and if I enter an invalid input (i.e. a string which does not have 1 or 2 or 3 as its first element) the program asks me to reenter the string until I get it right.

The problem is with 1 and 2. Whenever I pick "1 blahblah" as my input string, I get some weird error that says "Unhandled exception at at 0x74E93572 in hw3try3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x008FF35C." I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong. Someone please enlighten me. I will be eternally grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= InputString.length(); i++)` arrays and strings are indexed from `0`->`length-1`, your loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < InputString.length(); i++)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I fixed this part but now the loop is not working. If I enter a wrong input multiple times and then enter "1 blahblah" I do not get the expected output.